# angular 4 - create json with two array

Tags: json, angular

good day, I am needing to create a Json type object in agular 4 with 2 array one is the header and the other contains the information:

```
var valArray1 = ["registration", "id", "first_name","last_name"];

var valArray2 = ['2016-02-03',23, 'kevin','fox','2016-03-05',3, 'Beety','marks'];
```

at the moment I try to create it I get the next exit

```
{
 "objArray1":
    {"registration":"2016-03-05","id":3,"first_name":"Beety","last_name":"marks"},
 "objArray2":
    {}
}
```

when I aspire to have something in the following way:

```
{
    "registration": "2016-02-03",
    "id": "23",
    "first_name": "Kevin",
    "last_name": "Fox"
},
{
    "registration": "2016-03-05",
    "id": "3",
    "first_name": "Betty",
    "last_name": "marks"   
}
```

Thank you for your attention and help

Comment: You got a 'semi' working code, provide it on your question? Then we can help from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy with a bit of Lodash. All of this could be done with vanilla JS, but Lodash methods will never throw an exception and handle erronous inputs (i.e null, undefined) gracefully.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const valArray1 = ['registration', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name'];
const valArray2 = ['2016-02-03', 23, 'kevin', 'fox', '2016-03-05', 3, 'Beety', 'marks'];

const result = _.reduce(
  valArray2,
  (acc, value, index) => {
    const currentKeyIndex = index % _.size(valArray1);
    if (currentKeyIndex === 0) acc.push({ [valArray1[0]]: value });
    else _.set(acc, [_.lastIndexOf(acc) - 1, valArray1[currentKeyIndex]], value);
    return acc;
  },
  []
);

console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[ { registration: '2016-02-03',
    id: 23,
    first_name: 'kevin',
    last_name: 'fox' },
  { registration: '2016-03-05',
    id: 3,
    first_name: 'Beety',
    last_name: 'marks' } ]
```